# Rails 3 Action Controller Record Not Found

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, controller

I'm using jQuery UI Tabs with Ajax and I am getting an error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

The resource is [:3000/messages/profile_messages](http://:3000/messages/profile_messages)

If I go to http://localhost:3000/messages/profile_messages in my browser I get Action Controller: Exception caught:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in MessagesController#show

Couldn't find Message with ID=profile_messages

Rails.root: /Users/me/Desktop/myapp

app/controllers/messages_controller.rb:18:in `show'

Parameters:

{"id"=>"profile_messages"}
```

**In my `MessagesController#show`:**

```
def show
  @message = Message.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    format.xml  { render :xml => @message }
    format.js {render :layout => false }
  end
end
```

The MessagesController#show is for individual messages, but how can I make it work for what I'm trying to do? I'm new to Rails and programming so sorry if this is an obvious answer.

**Routes.rb:**

```
resources :users
resources :profiles
resources :session
resources :sessions
resources :messages do
  resources :responses
end
resource :messages do
  collection do
    get :profile_messages
  end
end
```

**rake routes:**

```
messages GET    /messages(.:format)  {:action=>"index", :controller=>"messages"}
          POST   /messages(.:format)  {:action=>"create", :controller=>"messages"}
new_message GET    /messages/new(.:format)  {:action=>"new", :controller=>"messages"}
edit_message GET    /messages/:id/edit(.:format)  {:action=>"edit",     :controller=>"messages"}
message GET    /messages/:id(.:format)  {:action=>"show", :controller=>"messages"}
         PUT    /messages/:id(.:format)  {:action=>"update", :controller=>"messages"}
         DELETE /messages/:id(.:format)  {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"messages"}
profile_messages_messages GET    /messages/profile_messages(.:format)               {:action=>"profile_messages", :controller=>"messages"}
         POST   /messages(.:format)  {:action=>"create", :controller=>"messages"}
new_messages GET    /messages/new(.:format)  {:action=>"new", :controller=>"messages"}
edit_messages GET    /messages/edit(.:format)  {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"messages"}
         GET    /messages(.:format)  {:action=>"show", :controller=>"messages"}
         PUT    /messages(.:format)  {:action=>"update", :controller=>"messages"}
         DELETE /messages(.:format)  {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"messages"}
```

**profile_messages method in MessagesController:**

```
def profile_messages
  @messages = User.find(@profile.user_id).messages
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.xml  { render :xml => @messages }
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you show us your routes.rb ?

Comment: Why you only have a questions_controller and no messages_controller ? Could you add the actual file and not the output of the rake routes please?

Comment: You beat me to it. I added the file and the `messages` side of the rake routes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With  http://localhost:3000/messages/profile_messages you are trying to access to the message with the id => profile_messages

What you might need to do is :

[http://localhost:3000/messages/:id/profile_messages](http://localhost:3000/messages/%3aid/profile_messages)

for example:

http://localhost:3000/messages/1/profile_messages

In your routes.rb, you might need to add something like:

```rb
resources :messages do
  member do
    get :profile_messages
  end
end
```

======== UPDATE ========

Based on this line

```
profile_messages_messages GET    /messages/profile_messages(.:format)               {:action=>"profile_messages", :controller=>"messages"}
```

Can you show us the method profile_messages from your controller messages ?

======== UPDATE ========

You should change your routes from

```rb
resources :users
resources :profiles
resources :session
resources :sessions
resources :messages do
  resources :responses
end
resource :messages do
  collection do
    get :profile_messages
  end
end
```

to

```rb
resources :users
resources :profiles
resources :session
resources :sessions
resources :messages do
  resources :responses
  get :profile_messages, :on => :collection
end
```

You could also add

```rb
match "/messages/profile_messages" => "messages#profile_message"
```

Comment: in your messages_controller is `@profile` is defined somewhere for the line `@messages = User.find(@profile.user_id).messages`

Comment: No @profile isn't defined anywhere in MessagesController. Should I define it in the `show` method or the `profile_messages` method?

Comment: Try to change the routes first but you will need to define it because it is called in the profile_messages method

Comment: So without the route match I get `Couldn't find Question with ID=profile_questions`. With the match (and changing "messages#profile_message" to "messages#profile_messages") I get `undefined method `user_id' for nil:NilClass` in `profile_messages` in `messages_controller.rb`. So I need to define it in `profile_messages` in `messages_controller.rb`.

Comment: Great, now you find need to define your `@profile` in profile_messages so it will be able to access the user_id.

Comment: Okay, something must not be right. I defined `@profile = Profile.find(params[:id])` and I get `Couldn't find Profile without an ID`.

Comment: The `params[:id]` is not define as your url is /messages/profile_messages there is no :id. Do you have a current_user method (only if you have an authentification)? if so you can do current_user.id

Comment: I ended up getting things to work in `profiles_controller.rb` instead of `messages_controller.rb`. However I still have a few issues. I put them in a new question if you've got some time: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7693012/rails-3-jquery-ui-tabs-issue-loading-with-ajax. Thanks for your help though!