# Rails 3 jQuery UI Tabs issue loading with Ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using jQuery UI Tabs to handle tabs my Rails 3 app. One tab is without Ajax, one is with Ajax. I'm new to programming and Rails, and while I got a ton of help from [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7682382/rails-3-action-controller-record-not-found/7682443#7682443) thus far I'm having two issues:

1. Clicking my Ajax link loads the entire site's layout in my `div`. I want to just load my template.
2. No matter which profile I view, the content loaded only applies to the current_user's messages.

Here's the container for the tabs:

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul id="infoContainer">
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">About</a></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Messages", '/profiles/profile_messages', :remote => true %></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
  </div>
</div>
```

The second link is where I see the entire site layout. Ideally what I want is to replace the About div with the my `profile_messages` template.

My `profiles_controller.rb`:

```
def profile_messages
  @profile = User.find(user.id).profile
  @messages = User.find(@profile.user_id).messages
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.xml  { render :xml => @messages }
  end
end
```

My `profile_messages.html.erb` template:

```
<div id="tabs-2">
<% for message in @user.messagse %>
  <div class="message">
  </div>
<% end %>
</div>
```

Here is my `routes.rb`:

```
match "/profiles/profile_messages" => "profiles#profile_messages"
resources :profiles do
  get :profile_messages, :on => :collection
end
```

My jQuery in `application.js`:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
        ajaxOptions: {
            error: function( xhr, status, index, anchor ) {
                $( anchor.hash ).html(
                    "There was an error loading this tab. Please try again." );
            }
        }
    });
});
```

I also have `profile_messages.js.erb`:

```
$( "#tabs" ).html( "<%= escape_javascript( render(@user.messages) ) %>" );
```

Any ideas on what's going on?

**UPDATE:** I got the layout to disappear by inserting the following into my `profile_messages`

```
def profile_messages
  @profile = User.find(user.id).profile
  @messages = User.find(@profile.user_id).messages
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render :layout => nil }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @messages }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in your controller. A few things about the profile_messages action:

```
def profile_messages
  @profile = User.find(user.id).profile
  @messages = User.find(@profile.user_id).messages
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.xml  { render :xml => @messages }
  end
end
```

1) where is `user.id` coming from? You should be sending some parameters with the ajax request, so unless 'user' is a protected method in your controller, you'll need to supply the `find` method with `params[:user_id]` or something similar.

2) Use `render :layout => false` to fix the template issue.

3) As a side note, your first two lines are all over the place. It would be easier (and faster) to do this:

```
@user = User.includes(:messages, :profile).find(params[:user_id])
@messages = @user.messages # already in memory
@profile = @user.profile # already in memory
```

Comment: In my `application_controller.rb`, current_user is protected. I add `render :layout => false` but it seems to cause my profile_messages to fail to load.

Comment: If I do `@user = User.includes(:questions, :profile).find(params[:user_id])` in `rails console` I get: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find User with ID=user_id